# Get Price for stripe integration (in form elements) in PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I integrate **Stripe** my website,

I find the script (works fine) but I want to put 4 articles to buy, so I need to get the price, and it doesn't work :/ I have put a hidden input, but impossible get the value

first my form (In modal) => I put an input with value 12 for example

```
<!-- Stylesheet file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<!-- Stripe JS library -->
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script src="js/checkout.js" STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY="<?php echo STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY; ?>" defer></script>

<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    
        <!-- Product Info -->
        <p> <?php echo $itemName; ?></p>
        <p><b>Price:</b> <?php echo '$'.$itemPrice.' '.$currency; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <!-- Display status message -->
        <div id="paymentResponse" class="hidden"></div>
        
        <!-- Display a payment form -->
        <form id="paymentFrm" class="hidden">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>NAME</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" class="field" placeholder="Enter name" required="" autofocus="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>EMAIL</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" class="field" placeholder="Enter email" required="">
            </div>

 <input type="hidden" class="field"  name="prix" id="prix" value="12" >
            
            <div id="paymentElement">
                <!--Stripe.js injects the Payment Element-->
            </div>
            
            <!-- Form submit button -->
            <button id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-success">
                <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
                <span id="buttonText">Pay Now</span>
            </button>
        </form>
        
        <!-- Display processing notification -->
        <div id="frmProcess" class="hidden">
            <span class="ring"></span> Processing...
        </div>
        
        <!-- Display re-initiate button -->
        <div id="payReinit" class="hidden">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href.split('?')[0]"><i class="rload"></i>Re-initiate Payment</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
// Get API Key
let STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = document.currentScript.getAttribute('STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY');

// Create an instance of the Stripe object and set your publishable API key
const stripe = Stripe(STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);

// Define card elements
let elements;

// Select payment form element
const paymentFrm = document.querySelector("#paymentFrm");

// Get payment_intent_client_secret param from URL
const clientSecretParam = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
    "payment_intent_client_secret"
);

// Check whether the payment_intent_client_secret is already exist in the URL
setProcessing(true);
if(!clientSecretParam){
    setProcessing(false);
    
    // Create an instance of the Elements UI library and attach the client secret
    initialize();
}

// Check the PaymentIntent creation status
checkStatus();

// Attach an event handler to payment form
paymentFrm.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

// Fetch a payment intent and capture the client secret
let payment_intent_id;
async function initialize() {
    const { id, clientSecret } = await fetch("payment_init.php", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ request_type:'create_payment_intent' }),
    }).then((r) => r.json());
    
    const appearance = {
        theme: 'stripe',
        rules: {
            '.Label': {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                textTransform: 'uppercase',
            }
        }
    };
    
    elements = stripe.elements({ clientSecret, appearance });
    
    const paymentElement = elements.create("payment");
    paymentElement.mount("#paymentElement");
    
    payment_intent_id = id;
}

// Card form submit handler
async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    
    let customer_name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    let customer_email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    let customer_prix = document.getElementById("prix").value;
    
    const { id, customer_id } = await fetch("payment_init.php", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ request_type:'create_customer', payment_intent_id: payment_intent_id, name: customer_name, email: customer_email, prix: customer_prix }),
    }).then((r) => r.json());
    
    const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
        elements,
        confirmParams: {
            // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
            return_url: window.location.href+'?customer_id='+customer_id,
        },
    });
    
    // This point will only be reached if there is an immediate error when
    // confirming the payment. Otherwise, your customer will be redirected to
    // your `return_url`. For some payment methods like iDEAL, your customer will
    // be redirected to an intermediate site first to authorize the payment, then
    // redirected to the `return_url`.
    if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
        showMessage(error.message);
    } else {
        showMessage("An unexpected error occured.");
    }
    
    setLoading(false);
}

// Fetch the PaymentIntent status after payment submission
async function checkStatus() {
    const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
        "payment_intent_client_secret"
    );
    
    const customerID = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
        "customer_id"
    );
    
    if (!clientSecret) {
        return;
    }
    
    const { paymentIntent } = await stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret);
    
    if (paymentIntent) {
        switch (paymentIntent.status) { 
            case "succeeded":
                // Post the transaction info to the server-side script and redirect to the payment status page
                fetch("payment_init.php", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ request_type:'payment_insert', payment_intent: paymentIntent, customer_id: customerID }),
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.payment_txn_id) {
                        window.location.href = '?o=shop&pid='+data.payment_txn_id;
                    } else {
                        showMessage(data.error);
                        setReinit();
                    }
                })
                .catch(console.error);
                
                break;
            case "processing":
                showMessage("Your payment is processing.");
                setReinit();
                break;
            case "requires_payment_method":
                showMessage("Your payment was not successful, please try again.");
                setReinit();
                break;
            default:
                showMessage("Something went wrong.");
                setReinit();
                break;
        }
    } else {
        showMessage("Something went wrong.");
        setReinit();
    }
}


// Display message
function showMessage(messageText) {
    const messageContainer = document.querySelector("#paymentResponse");
    
    messageContainer.classList.remove("hidden");
    messageContainer.textContent = messageText;
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        messageContainer.classList.add("hidden");
        messageText.textContent = "";
    }, 5000);
}

// Show a spinner on payment submission
function setLoading(isLoading) {
    if (isLoading) {
        // Disable the button and show a spinner
        document.querySelector("#submitBtn").disabled = true;
        document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
        document.querySelector("#buttonText").classList.add("hidden");
    } else {
        // Enable the button and hide spinner
        document.querySelector("#submitBtn").disabled = false;
        document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
        document.querySelector("#buttonText").classList.remove("hidden");
    }
}

// Show a spinner on payment form processing
function setProcessing(isProcessing) {
    if (isProcessing) {
        paymentFrm.classList.add("hidden");
        document.querySelector("#frmProcess").classList.remove("hidden");
    } else {
        paymentFrm.classList.remove("hidden");
        document.querySelector("#frmProcess").classList.add("hidden");
    }
}

// Show payment re-initiate button
function setReinit() {
    document.querySelector("#frmProcess").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#payReinit").classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

and the payment_init.php where i need to get price

```
<?php 
 
// Include the configuration file 
require_once 'config.php'; 
 
// Include the database connection file 
include_once 'dbConnect.php'; 
 
 $itemPrice = $_POST['prix'];
 
// Include the Stripe PHP library 
//require_once 'stripe-php/init.php'; 
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
 
// Set API key 
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_API_KEY); 
 
// Retrieve JSON from POST body 
$jsonStr = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr); 

if($jsonObj->request_type == 'create_payment_intent'){ 
     
    // Define item price and convert to cents 
    $itemPriceCents = round($itemPrice*100); 
     
    // Set content type to JSON 
    header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
     
    try { 
        // Create PaymentIntent with amount and currency 
        $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([ 
            'amount' => $itemPriceCents, 
            'currency' => $currency, 
            'description' => $itemName, 
            'payment_method_types' => [ 
                'card' 
            ] 
        ]); 
     
        $output = [ 
            'id' => $paymentIntent->id, 
            'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret 
        ]; 
     
        echo json_encode($output); 
    } catch (Error $e) { 
        http_response_code(500); 
        echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]); 
    } 
}elseif($jsonObj->request_type == 'create_customer'){ 
    $payment_intent_id = !empty($jsonObj->payment_intent_id)?$jsonObj->payment_intent_id:''; 
    $name = !empty($jsonObj->name)?$jsonObj->name:''; 
    $email = !empty($jsonObj->email)?$jsonObj->email:''; 
     
    // Ajout client a la base
    try {   
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(  
            'name' => $name,  
            'email' => $email 
        ));  
    }catch(Exception $e) {   
        $api_error = $e->getMessage();   
    } 
     
    if(empty($api_error) && $customer){ 
        try { 
            // Mise a jour de l'intention avec l'id du client  
            $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::update($payment_intent_id, [ 
                'customer' => $customer->id 
            ]); 
        } catch (Exception $e) {  
            // pour apres 
        } 
         
        $output = [ 
            'id' => $payment_intent_id, 
            'customer_id' => $customer->id 
        ]; 
        echo json_encode($output); 
    }else{ 
        http_response_code(500); 
        echo json_encode(['error' => $api_error]); 
    } 
}elseif($jsonObj->request_type == 'payment_insert'){ 
    $payment_intent = !empty($jsonObj->payment_intent)?$jsonObj->payment_intent:''; 
    $customer_id = !empty($jsonObj->customer_id)?$jsonObj->customer_id:''; 
     
    // Retrieve customer info 
    try {   
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customer_id);  
    }catch(Exception $e) {   
        $api_error = $e->getMessage();   
    } 
     
    // Check whether the charge was successful 
    if(!empty($payment_intent) && $payment_intent->status == 'succeeded'){ 
        // Transaction details  
        $transaction_id = $payment_intent->id; 
        $paid_amount = $payment_intent->amount; 
        $paid_amount = ($paid_amount/100); 
        $paid_currency = $payment_intent->currency; 
        $payment_status = $payment_intent->status; 
         
        $customer_name = $customer_email = ''; 
        if(!empty($customer)){ 
            $customer_name = !empty($customer->name)?$customer->name:''; 
            $customer_email = !empty($customer->email)?$customer->email:''; 
        } 
         
        // Check if any transaction data is exists already with the same TXN ID 
        $sqlQ = "SELECT id FROM transactions WHERE txn_id = ?"; 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sqlQ);  
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $transaction_id); 
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->bind_result($row_id); 
        $stmt->fetch(); 
         
        $payment_id = 0; 
        if(!empty($row_id)){ 
            $payment_id = $row_id; 
        }else{ 
            // Insert transaction data into the database 
            $sqlQ = "INSERT INTO transactions (customer_name,customer_email,item_name,item_price,item_price_currency,paid_amount,paid_amount_currency,txn_id,payment_status,created,modified) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW(),NOW())"; 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sqlQ); 
            $stmt->bind_param("sssdsdsss", $customer_name, $customer_email, $itemName, $itemPrice, $currency, $paid_amount, $paid_currency, $transaction_id, $payment_status); 
            $insert = $stmt->execute(); 
             
            if($insert){ 
                $payment_id = $stmt->insert_id; 
            } 
        } 
         
        $output = [ 
            'payment_txn_id' => base64_encode($transaction_id) 
        ]; 
        echo json_encode($output); 
    }else{ 
        http_response_code(500); 
        echo json_encode(['error' => 'Transaction has been failed!']); 
    } 
} 
 
?>
```